# Cannot read property 'query' of null?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

```
var express = require('express');
var pg = require('pg');
var app = express();

var connectionString = "postgres://...";

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    pg.connect(connectionString, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("not able to get connection " + err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empid=$1', [1], function (err, result) {
                done(); // closing the connection;
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send(err);

                }
                res.status(200).send(result.rows);

            });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running.. on Port 3000');
});
```

This is my nodejs file and the connectionString is database information that connected heroku and postgreSQL.

But when I run this one, I only get

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empid=$1', [1], function (err, result) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: That means `client` is `null`.

Comment: Which postgres module are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In your error handler here:

```
    if (err) {
        console.log("not able to get connection " + err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    client.query(...)
```

You need to add a return so that after you send the error status, the code does not continue to try to execute `client.query()` because `client` does not have a valid value in it if there was an error.  So, change to this:

```
    if (err) {
        console.log("not able to get connection " + err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
        return;
    }
    client.query(...)
```

---

Though it has less of a consequence, the same is true here:

```
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);

            }
            res.status(200).send(result.rows);
```

Where you need to add a return:

```
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(200).send(result.rows);
```

The overall issue in these two cases is that while `res.status(...).send(...)` sends the response back to the client, it does not stop your code from continuing to execute after that so you still need proper flow control with `if/else` or an appropriate `return` to control the flow of execution of the code so after an error it doesn't immediately go execute other parts of the code that you don't want it to.

Comment: @김기훈 - Well, this is something to fix - apparently there are more issues.  Perhaps you aren't using the `pg.connect()` function correctly.  I don't know that API, but I will look it up.  Which exact postgres module are you using?  Can you provide a link to it on NPM?

Comment: @김기훈 - The doc I see [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling) and [here](https://node-postgres.com/api/client) both show different sequences for connecting than you show.  One constructs a Pool object, the other constructs a Client object and neither looks like your code.  Are you sure your method of connecting is correct?

Comment: @김기훈 - Did you figure out your question?